# Polymorphic Return Types Depending on Context

Tags: haskell, types

I'm playing around with implementing a Redis client-library in Haskell and it is my goal to encode, as much as possible, the semantics of the Redis commands in Haskell's type system. Redis, for those who don't know, is a datastore, accessed over the network. I will use it to exemplify my problem, but Redis is not the focus of this question.

## An Example Function

Consider the function

```
get :: (RedisValue a) => Key -> Redis a
get k = decodeValue <$> sendCommand ["GET", key]
```

It sends a command to the datastore and returns a value stored under the given `Key` (for this example, you can consider `type Key = String`). As for the return-type:

- `Redis` is an instance of `Monad` and `MonadIO`. It encapsulates information about the network connection. `sendCommand` sends the request and returns the datastore's reply.
- `a` is polymorphic, for example either `String`s or `ByteString`s can be returned, depending on the context.

The following code should clarify the text above.

```
data Redis a = ...

instance MonadIO Redis where ...
instance Monad Redis where ...

sendCommand :: [String] -> Redis String

class RedisValue a where
    decodeValue :: String -> a

-- example instances
instance RedisValue String where ...
instance RedisValue ByteString where ...
```

## Different Context, Different Types

Redis supports a simple form of transactions. In a transaction most commands can be sent the same as outside of a transaction. However their execution is delayed until the user sends the commit command (which is called `exec` in Redis). Inside the transaction, the datastore only returns an acknowledgment that the command is stored for later execution. Upon commit (`exec`) all results of all stored commands are returned.

This means that the `get`-function from above looks a bit different in the context of a transaction:

```
get :: (RedisStatus a) => Key -> RedisTransaction a
get k = decodeStatus <$> sendCommand ["GET", key]
```

Note that:

- The monadic type is now `RedisTransaction` to indicate the transaction context.
- The `a` return type is now any instance of `RedisStatus`. There is an overlap between instances of `RedisValue` and `RedisStatus`. For example `String` is in both classes. A specialized `Status` data type might be only in the `RedisStatus` class.

## The Actual Question

My question is, how can I write a function `get` that works in both contexts, with context-appropriate return type classes. What I need is

- a way to give `get` a return type "either Redis or RedisTransaction",
- The type `a` to be an instance of `RedisValue` in the `Redis` context and an instance of `RedisStatus` in the `RedisTransaction` context.
- A function `decode` that automagically does the right thing, depending on the context. I assume this must come from a (multi-param) type class.

If you know how I can do this or have a pointer to some example code or even an article, you will have my thanks!

Comment: Could you create two different functions - one for the `Redis` context and one for the `RedisTransaction` context?

Comment: Is it the case that a single `RedisValue` can be represented either as a `String` or a `ByteString`, or that the `RedisValue` for a given `Key` is one of the two, but not both? @sclv's solution should work if the former is true, but the latter would require some extra tricks.

Comment: Also, this is a really, really good first SO question. Please stick around!

Comment: Thanks, acfoltzer. Regarding your question: A single RedisValue can be represented as either a String or a ByteString (or even something else).

Comment: Cable729, yes I could. From a usability and noob-friendliness point-of-view that would probably be best, since two separate functions (and their types) `get` and `getTx` are much easier to understand than a combined function. However, Redis has more than 100 commands, most of which can be used in both contexts. This would result in a lot of duplication.

Comment: I'd actually probably move the commands into two different modules, and then the user could import both qualified or switch between them.

Answer (score 5):

First, I think that it would be better to have two different get commands. That said, here's an approach.

```
class RedisGet m a where
    get :: Key -> m a

instance (RedisValue a) => RedisGet Redis a where...

instance (RedisStatus a) => RedisGet RedisTransaction a where...
```

You need 
MPTCs, but no FunDeps or Type Families. Every use of get requires that enough information be available to determine both the `m` and `a` uniquely.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that multiparameter type classes are a good fit here. Here's an approach:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}

newtype Redis a = Redis (IO a) deriving Monad
newtype RedisTransaction a = RedisTransaction (IO a) deriving Monad

newtype Key    = Key {unKey :: String}
newtype Value  = Value {unValue :: String}
newtype Status = Status {unStatus :: String}

class Monad m => RedisMonad m a | m -> a where
  sendCommand :: [String] -> m a

instance RedisMonad Redis Value where
  sendCommand = undefined -- TODO: provide implementation                       

instance RedisMonad RedisTransaction Status where
  sendCommand = undefined -- TODO: provide implementation                       

class Decodable a b where
  decode :: a -> b

instance Decodable Status String where
  decode = unStatus

instance Decodable Value String where
  decode = unValue

get :: (RedisMonad m a, Decodable a b) => Key -> m b
get k = do
  response <- sendCommand ["GET", unKey k]
  return (decode response)
```

Note the use of the type isomorphisms for `Value` and `Status`: it makes things slightly stronger typed as the `String`s you are having produced by your implementations of `sendCommand` obviously are not just arbitrary sequences of characters but instead adhere to some fixed formats for return values and statuses.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that there's nothing special about a type depending on context--that happens all the time with type inference. The type of `[]` is `[a]`, but when you use it in something like `True : []` the type will be specialized to `[Bool]` in context.

What changes matters is if you want the *implementation* of a function, or the definition of a value, to depend on its type. If that type is then inferred from context in the normal way, you end up with a function that does something "different" depending on context. Type-dependent implementation is the main purpose of using type classes.

Now, to answer your specific questions:

> - a way to give `get` a return type "either Redis or RedisTransaction",

This requires only a variable in the type signature of `get`, e.g. `get :: Key -> f a`. The `f` will be filled in as either `Redis` or `RedisTransaction` depending on context.

> - The type `a` to be an instance of `RedisValue` in the `Redis` context and an instance of `RedisStatus` in the `RedisTransaction` context.

Since both `a` and the context type will be inferred from use, what you're really after here is *restricting* the possible types, which amounts to expecting a type-checking error if they don't match up. This is another purpose of type classes, and *could* be implemented with an appropriate class constraint on the context type variable:

```
get :: (ContextValue (f a)) => Key -> f a

class ContextValue a
instance (RedisValue a) => ContextValue (Redis a)
instance (RedisStatus a) => ContextValue (RedisTransaction a)
```

Or something like that. But that alone isn't enough for your purposes, because...

> - A function `decode` that automagically does the right thing, depending on the context. I assume this must come from a (multi-param) type class.

This implies selecting an implementation for `decode` based on the type, which means making it part of a type class such as the above `ContextValue`. How you handle this depends on what the type for `decode` needs to be--if the result type needs to be something like `f String -> f a` where `f` is the monadic context, then you'll probably need something a bit more elaborate, like in dblhelix's answer. If you only need `String -> f a`, then you could add it to the above `ContextValue` class directly.